# hp probook 6570b flash bios utility

Tags: bios

i have an hp probook 6570b i need to flash the bios but cant find any specific flash utility based on my motherboard   can some one please help    Hewlett-Packard 17AB motherboard and Hewlett-Packard 68ICE bios

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to flash the BIOS in the first place? BIOS manufacturer has a new version?

The best place to download utilities / drivers / etc. for brand name PCs is from the manufacturer support site. If there's a BIOS update, it will be available from there with all necessary tools and instructions needed to install it. Downloading these from original manufacturer website isn't necessarily a good idea, as there may be some fine-tunings made by the brand manufacturer which the original mfg isn't supporting.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-search.html?tab=1#!&qryterm=probook+6570b&search_searchtype=s-002